# 200 status response to Slack interactive message not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slack-api

I am integrating my app with Slack, in particular interactive messages. I have enabled interactive messages and am using ngrok to route the action URL to my local development machine.

The following appears in a Slack channel:

[image: screenshot from Slack]

Clicking yes delivers a payload to my dev machine (truncated example):

```
{"payload"=>"{\"actions\":[{\"name\":\"approved\",\"type\":\"button\",\"value\":\"yes\"}]
```

Slack requires acknowledgment of the request within 3000ms to avoid timeout. I have been struggling and have now commented out all controller code expect `head :ok`.

```
def incoming
  head :ok
end
```

This appears in my logs as processed by the relevant route. ngrok shows a sub-1000ms response time but I still get the following in Slack.[image: slack screenshot]

I'm at a loss as to why the response is not being accepted by Slack. I've tried `head :ok`, `head :no_content`, `render status: 200`.

Comment: IIRC Slack requires a body to the response. If that's the issue here, `render text: 'ok'` should do the trick.

Comment: Still receiving the timeout error. `render text: 'ok'` is the first thing in my controller action and definitely responds within the 3000ms limit

Comment: Can you try responding with a new message, that will replace the interactive message? If you respond with error or `response_url` (as [documented here](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding)) do you see a different behavior from Slack?

Comment: please share ngrock logs, do you even receive the request properly?